# Error in installing bootstrap for angular 4 cli

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When I try to install bootstrap in angular4 cli (windows), it happens the following error

`npm install bootstrap --save`

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: No one should use that beta anymore.

Comment: no , it is an error i maked "npm install bootstrap --save"

Comment: It skipped an optional dependency so you should be ok. Does it work?

Comment: No..  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You know if bootstrap was installed correctly if you can find the `bootstrap` folder in the parent `node_modules` folder.  I would also try this if you haven't already:

1. Install Bootstrap `npm install --save bootstrap`
2. Import Bootstrap into either

   - styles.css using `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`, or
   - .angular-cli.json via the styles property:

     `"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
     ],`

Comment: are you sure you typed in `npm install bootstrap --save` in the correct directory (in your root folder)?

Answer (score 0):

use these command it works for me

```
npm install bootstrap
```

then include in angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
```